# mod_rewrite PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My URL currently looks like that

> http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?videoID=6nR9nsKTx4g

but I want to access the page via

> http://www.mydomain.com/6nR9nsKTx4g

I tried it like that

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?videoID=$1 [L]
```

but the videoID is not transmitted. What's wrong with that code?
Thanks

Comment: Though it probably doesn't make a difference in this case, you could just use `(.*)`.

Comment: Seems to be alright. Is the videoID empty? try print_r($_GET); to see if you've made a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the QSA, this appends the query string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?videoID=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Appending the query string won't work on this, since the original URL does not have a query string.

Comment: That's weird. My understanding of how QSA works must be off. I thought it just appended the original query data onto the rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason why this wouldn't work, looking at the code you've used it looks spot on.

Try adding phpinfo(); die(); to the top of your code and check the _GET variables to ensure the variable has been set.

Comment: When using die(); on http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?videoID=6nR9nsKTx4g or http://www.mydomain.com/6nR9nsKTx4g I get "index.php".